# Broken styles with amcharts4

Tags: amcharts, laravel-mix, amcharts4

I'm trying to import amcharts' parts in the vue component like that:

```
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
```

but it breaks styles of the site: final css file contains only `/* (ignored) *//* (ignored) *//* (ignored) */` instead of the actual styles. I've found a [thread on the github](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1641) with the same problem, but it was close w/o any resolution.

Could anyone help me to figure out the reason of this behavior and the actual fix?

**amcharts:** 4.10.5; **Webpack:** 4.43.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've found a solution for this.

You need to remove those generated files (if they were created):

```
public/vendors~xlsx.js
public/xlsx.js
public/vendors~pdfmake.js
public/vendors~canvg.js
```

Add this to the webpack configuration (for laravel-mix add this inside the `mix.webpackConfig({...})` construction):

```
{
  externals: function (context, request, callback) {
    if (/xlsx|canvg|pdfmake/.test(request)) {
      return callback(null, "commonjs " + request);
    }
    callback();
  }
}
```

More details are [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/integrations/using-webpack/#Large_file_sizes).